# Pre-Populating a CCK Flexifield/Multigroup?

Tags: 6, nodes, entities

I'm using a repeating fieldset module (Flexifield, somewhat similar to CCK3 Multigroup) to create a measurement sheet content type. In this, the user is allowed to create an unlimited number of rooms, each defined by five fields: *name*, *level*, *width*, *length*, *area*.

It would be really useful to pre-populate about ten of these rows (e.g. "Kitchen," "Bathroom," "Living Room").

How would one go about programmatically creating and filling CCK fields with number of values set to "Unlimited"?

Comment: Sigh... Yet another bounty fail...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.

Comment: I've seen that before; does that work with fields supplied by a AHAH request?

Comment: Just tried using it, Prepopulate does **not** generate new rows when the "Add another" button is clicked for infinitely valued Flexifield fields; as such, Prepopulate.module is useless to me.

Comment: Have you tried using hook_form_alter to set the values?

Comment: @Landing -- I've tried a few different ways to no avail; if the input has the name `field_levels[0][value][field_level_label][0][value]`, would the $form variable be: `$form['field_levels'][0]['value']['field_level_label'][0]['value']`?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom module's form alter function, you can use this code to alter a multivalue field. I use the [form inspect](http://drupal.org/project/forminspect) module so I can find the form structure of each field. I haven't tested this as a flexifield, but I think it will still work.

```
$form['field_name']['0']['#default_value']['value'] =t('hello');

$form['field_name']['1']['#default_value']['value'] =t('world');
```

Comment: Useful! I'll give that a shot later tonight.

Comment: Form Inspect doesn't give any options for the fields within the flexifield type...